# PostgreSQL - Removing Unused Index on Check Constraint column

Tags: postgresql, index, check-constraints

I used the script from [this](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/) blog to identify the unused index on my database. It returns an index which is on a column called `result` where I have a check constraint on that column.

So removing this index will impact the check constraint performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will removing this index impact the check constraint performance?

No, it will not.

Check constraints only operate on the columns of a single row, not on multiple rows. So it is completely unaffected by the existence (or absence) of an index.